# How to find out request count to each instance behind an ALB in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multiple-instances, amazon-alb

I have 50-60 aws instances running behind an ALB in AWS. I can get the total request count in the cloudwatch monitoring section, but is there anyway I can get to know how many requests are actually being directed to each instances from the ALB in real time.

Comment: If you need a rough idea: divide by 50-60. If you need it more exact than that, add CloudWatch metrics for the individual instances' webserver access logs.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish? There isn't a simple way to do this with default metrics in Cloudwatch.

However, AWS now supports "Metric Math" if you wanted to use that to calculate a value.  You could use that and a network in / out metric to estimate the traffic per instance, or you could use a custom metric from the instance.

If it doesn't need to be real-time, you could process the instance logs, push them into firehose or cloudwatch logs and build metrics off that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? - I'm using spotinst for scaling up instances and I have 2 different instance types present. I wanna know the number of requests each instance can handle before they become unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

For access logs it should be possible to enable ALB logs, and analyze them. The field target contains the information to which instance the request was routed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-log-entry-format

Another way to find out the maximim amount of requests for an instance type is to setup a loadtest witb e.g. Apache Jmeter, build a set of requests from e.g. ALB logs, and run them against a single instance while monitoring the instance metrics.
Doing so, make sure TLS is terminated the same way as in the production setup. TLS can have a major impact on test results with high request counts.
In case you have a ALB / ELB in the test calls be aware that these need time to ramp up or "pre-heat" them as otherwise requests could be dropped there.